# How to add custom header to retrofit request body part?

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data, retrofit2

So I am building a multipart request using retrofit and I want to add a custom header to one one of the part. I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to be working.

[image: My REQUEST]

The photo shows a body request that contains 4 parts. Each part contains a body and a header, what I want is to add a custom header to the selected part. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just to answer my own question, I create a part with an image and a custom header like this:

```
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.create(
    Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"" + "namevalue" + "\";" + " filename=\"" + filenamevalue + "\"", custom_header_name, custom_header_value),
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), multimedia.getMedia())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, currently there is no way to add headers directly to the `Part` via Retrofit.  You can construct each part yourself as a  `Okhttp3.MultipartBody.Part` and pass that to retrofit as a `@Part` parameter.  The downside is that you lose using retrofit's converters and have to convert your data into the part body yourself.

I submitted pull request to add a feature to allow it [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/2126).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will give it a try and see how it goes. Also I noticed that you posted an issue as well on their github page, thank you again.

Comment: Yes, it seemed like an easy thing to add.  We'll see if it gets accepted or not.

Comment: Can you please help me with some code? I have tried doing it myself, the headers worked just fine but the file was not recognized by the server