# How to add header to multi part request?

Tags: android, post, http-headers, http-post, retrofit2

I have a multipart request that has 3 parts, each part contains its own body and header, so what I want is to add a custom header on one of the parts. I have tried to build the request with retrofit and okhttp but they don't provide the option to do so. Any ideas?

EDIT : This is based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164123/how-to-add-custom-header-to-retrofit-request-body-part)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
public HttpResponse multiPartRequest(String url, String token, File file) {

client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

HttpResponse response = null;

DRPContentForUpload content = new DRPContentForUpload(file);
String jsonObject = DRPJSONConverter.toJson(content);
String BOUNDARY= "--eriksboundry--";

request.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+BOUNDARY);
request.addHeader("X-AUTHORIZATION",token);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,BOUNDARY,Charset.defaultCharset());
try {


    entity.addPart("file01", new StringBody(jsonObject));

    entity.addPart("file01", new FileBody(file));

    request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    Log.v("encoding exception","E::: "+e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+BOUNDARY);
request.setEntity(entity);

try {




    response = client.execute(request);



} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}


return response;
```

}

Comment: from the looks of it it is a standard request with no custom header for one of its part, for example part 1 which could be a file would have the standard headers plus extra. does that make more sense?